# Custom Cursor Moves Slow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written the code below to create a custom cursor style on my webpage, but the cursor moves very slow across the webpage. What is causing the slowness?

```js
var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
cursor.style.transition = "ease-in-out .2s";
document.onmousedown = () => {
  cursor.style.transform = "scale(0.4)";
};

document.onmouseup = () => {
  cursor.style.transform = "scale(1)";
};

document.onmousemove = (e) => {
  cursor.style.top = ((e.clientY - 15) + "px");
  cursor.style.left = ((e.clientX) + "px");
};
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor">o</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Why is the cursor firing when its away from this"? And do you have a snippet to show?

Comment: I accidentally pasted the css comment from another place, and theres the snippet
@ale917k

Answer (score 2):

That is due to the transition animation applied to the cursor. See `line 2`, and consider that:

- `0.1s` represents the transition `duration`
- `ease-in-out` or `linear` represent the transition `easing` (e.a. what was causing you that annoying and bouncy delay).

If you want to know more about different transition easings, I'd suggest you having a look at it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/).

```js
var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
cursor.style.transition = "linear 0.1s";
document.onmousedown = () => {
    cursor.style.transform = "scale(0.4)";
};

document.onmouseup = () => {
    cursor.style.transform = "scale(1)";
};

document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    cursor.style.top = ((e.clientY - 15) + "px");
    cursor.style.left = ((e.clientX) + "px");
};
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: none;
  /*Why is the cursor firing when its away from this*/
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor">o</div>
```

Little suggestion on a side, is to delete line two and add the transition on css instead: `transition: all 0.1s linear;` - This change doesn't actually modify any functionality, but it makes your code neattier.

The reason, is that styles should be kept in CSS whenever possible, leaving Javascript to handle styles only if needed (in this case, inside the event listeners such as onmousedown, onmouseup, ecc.)